# Object_list always empty

Tags: python, django

the app is working this way. That i have a simple news adding model as below:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    publication_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField()
```

the view

```
def homepage(request):
  posts= News.objects.all() #.get(title="aaa")
  return render_to_response('homepage.html', {'a':posts})
```

and finally the tamplate:

```
{% for b in a.object_list %}
   <li> title:{{ b.title }}</li>
{%empty %}
   EMPTY
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately it always sais 'EMPTY'. However if i take the '.get(title="aaa")' option instead of '.all()' (the commented part) I got the right title and content of the message with title 'aaa'.
Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for Your  expertise.

EDIT
I'm sorry I didn't have written the template for the get option Well off course the 'get' verion of template differs. It looks like this:

```
 {{a.title}} {{a.content}
```

And it works printing the expected title and message content So the 'get' works with the template and the 'for' didn't iterate over the QuerySet returned by all(). I am beginner but object_list is supposed to be the representation for querySet passed in render_on_request as a element of dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

When you use *get*, the variable *posts* contains an **instance** of *News*. On the other hand, if you use *.all()*, *posts* will contain a **queryset**. So first I would suggest you use *filter* instead of *get*, so *posts* would always be a queryset, and therefore you wouldn't have such an inconsistent behaviour ...

Answer (score 0):

Please post the exact code you are running. There is no way that either of your alternatives would work with `a.object_list`, because there is no definition of object_list anywhere and it's not a built-in Django property.

And assuming you actually mean that `for b in a` doesn't work in the first code but does in the second, this is not true either, because with `.get` you won't have anything to iterate through with `for`.

However, let's assume what you actually did was pass the results of `.all()` to the template, and the template didn't have the `for` loop. That wouldn't work, because `all()` - like `filter()` - returns a QuerySet, which must be iterated through. For the same reason, `get()` wouldn't work *with* a `for` loop.

**Edited after comment** "object_list is supposed to be the representation for querySet passed in render_on_request " - no, it isn't. Where did you get that idea? If you pass a queryset called `a` to the template, then you iterate through `a`, nothing else. `object_list` is the name that is used by default in generic views for the queryset itself - ie what you have called `a` - but in your own views you call it what you like, and use it with the name you have given it.

**Edited after second comment** I don't know why this should be confusing. You've invented a need for `object_list` where there is no such variable, and no need for one. Just do as I said originally - `{% for b in a %}`.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't have written the template for the get option Well off course the 'get' verion of template differs. It looks like this:

 {{a.title}} {{a.content} 

And it works printing the expected title and message content So the 'get' works with the template and the 'for' didn't iterate over the QuerySet returned by all(). I am beginner but object_list is supposed to be the representation for querySet passed in render_on_request as a element of dictionary?

Comment: Well this seems confusing. The code I gave You is all I put from the tutorial i have been working on. What is missing then? I just want to distplay in the 'for' tag all simple blog entries with title, content. Where and how should be the 'object-list definition' You were mentioning put?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to iterate over something like this:

```
for object in object_list:
    print object
```

object_list needs to support iterating. list, tuple, dict, and other types support that. You can define your own iterator class by giving it a **iter** method. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) for that.

Now, in your example

```
return render_to_response('homepage.html', {'a':posts})
```

posts is a Queryset instance that supports iterating. Think of it this way:

```
{% for b in News.objects.all %}
```

this is what you would like to have, but what you actually did is this:

```
{% for b in News.objects.all.object_list %}
```

But News.objects.all does not have an object_list attribute!

News.objects.all is what your object_list should be, so just write:

```
{% for b in a %}
```